# Rails 4.2 form error handling outside controller default view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following the official [starter guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) from rails guides. It's a great tutorial but I'm having doubts about how to handle form errors display for the comments form inside the article view.

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
 <p>
   <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
 </p>
 <p>
   <%= f.label :body %><br>
   <%= f.text_area :body %>
 </p>
 <p>
   <%= f.submit %>
 </p>
```

I don't know if this is something so simple to see that the guides don't bother to explain about it or is something more complex that it looks like.

What is the best process to display form errors after submission in a outside view in rails 4.2?

Also, as an aside note. What is the form workflow between different views and controllers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your `create` action you can do:

```
def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment = @article.comments.build(params[:comment])
  @comment.user = current_user
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  else
    render 'new', locals: { errors: @comment.errors.full_messages }
  end
end
```

The idea is that in your `create` action you try to save a new record. If everything is fine, the user will be redirected to the `#show` action of the article. Otherwise, Rails will render again the 'new' template. This time errors will be passed to your view. So you should add in your view validation for `errors` object and iterate over them (it's array of Strings) to display all messages in case that there are error messages.

Comment: My question is more regarding on how to show comments errors inside the show view of the article. You have any thoughts on how to do this approach? I just don't want to render the new view from comment when the errors happen.